# SpriteKit frame incorrect

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I'm creating a simple game.  I'm trying to set the frame as an `physicsBody` so the plane, never falls below the screen.  The function below stops it from falling all the way off, but the SKSpriteNode falls just out of view before stopping.

```
func setBoundry(view: SKView) {
    // Create ground
    var boundry = SKNode()
    boundry.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: view.frame)
    boundry.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    boundry.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Plane
    boundry.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Boundry | PhysicsCategory.Collidable

    self.addChild(boundry)
}
```

Plane is being created like this...

```
func createPlane(sceneView: SKView) {
    let planeTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "planeRed1")
    let planeTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "planeRed2")
    let planeTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "planeRed3")

    // Animate plans propeller
    let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([planeTexture, planeTexture1, planeTexture2], timePerFrame: 0.05)
    let makePropellerSpin = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation)

    // Set planes position
    plane = SKSpriteNode(texture: planeTexture)
    plane.position = CGPointMake(size.width/4, size.height/2)

    plane.runAction(makePropellerSpin)

    plane.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(plane.size.width, plane.size.height))
    plane.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    plane.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    plane.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Plane
    plane.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Collidable | PhysicsCategory.Boundry
    plane.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Collidable | PhysicsCategory.Boundry

    // Set elevation
    plane.zPosition = 5

    self.addChild(plane)
}
```

Comment: You're definitely calling the method?

Comment: yes from `override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)`

Comment: Make your question clear what do you want to achieve whether you want adjust frame or you want SKSprite node not to go out of screen ??? Be clear "I'm trying to set the frame as an physicsBody so the plane" it doesn't make any sense to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`contactTestBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/contactTestBitMask) for your boundry node and also set the physics for your plane-node:

```
boundry.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.YourPlayerEnum
```

Also check out the [`collisionBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/collisionBitMask) property of the physicsbody.

Comment: I updated both `contactTestBitMask` and `CollisionBitMask`...but still not working correctly.  I edited the question with the code that creates the plane as well.